# Restricting supported orientation to specific storyboard in multi storyboard app

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard, xcode5, uistoryboard

I have multi storyboard in my app and  i want to keep a storyboard orientation to portrait. 
Is it is possible ?? If yes how??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why multi storyboard? more details on multi-storyboard pls...

Comment: @FahimParkar: because i want separate storyboard for separate module . It is considered as the best practice i hope.

Comment: I will say multiple storyboard is bad idea as it will make app heavy and compiling/ running takes more time...

Comment: check my answer... hope this is what you need...

Comment: Please add the essential parts of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done... (below is example for only landscape orientation for app)

Create custom navigation controller

### CustomNavigationController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;

@end
```

### CustomNavigationController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (![[self.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"ViewController")])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
}
```

Include below in all files where you want only landscape...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    NSLog(@"1. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation");
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait) {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    }

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    ||(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```